# How to avoid having a lot of props for filter component React

Tags: reactjs

So I have a React component which has a child component with some filters:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const [a, setA] = useState('whatever');
   const [b, setB] = useState('whatever');
   const [c, setC] = useState('whatever');
   const [d, setD] = useState('whatever');
   const [e, setE] = useState('whatever');

   return <FilterComponent
              a={a}
              setA={setA}
              b={b}
              setB={setB}
              c={c}
              setC={setC}
              d={d}
              setD={setD}
              e={e}
              setE={setE}
          />

}
```

Is there a way to avoid something like this? Of course the variables are not called a, b, c, etc... it's just for the example.

Answer (score 1):

You mean not having so many states, but a common one?

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [alphabet, setAlphabet] = useState({
       a: 'whatever',
       b: 'whatever',
       c: 'whatever',
       d: 'whatever',
       e: 'whatever',
    });

    return <FilterComponent
              alphabet={alphabet}
              setAlphabet={setAlphabet}
          />

    }
```

Official doc [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables)

Comment: Is this a good practice? Also makes it harder to change state because you'd have to do: setAlphabet(prev => {...prev, b: 'whatever' }), but idk

Comment: Depens on if its related data

Comment: Ok I guess filters are related data so it's okay

Comment: @nick if it answer your question, i apreciate if you mark it as valid